# Same Entity referred twice in another Entity is creating issue while saving parent with children

Tags: entity-framework

I am having the data model as follows.

```
class KnowledgeDocument
{
   public int? Id {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<KDValueCreation> KDValueCreations { get; set; }
}

class KDValueCreation
{
    public int? Id{get; set;}
    public int? KDReferenceId { get; set; }
    public virtual KnowledgeDocument KDReference { get; set; }
    public int KnowledgeDocumentId { get; set; }
    public virtual KnowledgeDocument KnowledgeDocument { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount {get; set;}
}
```

Now, when I am trying to create a new `KnowledgeDocument` along with `KDValueCreations` as follows.

```
KnowledgeDocument kd = new KnowledgeDocument();

kd.KDValueCreations.Add(new KDValueCreation{ Amount = "500000"});
```

When I save the kd, kd is saved without any issue and in KDValueCreation, 1 record is created and both KDReferenceId and KnowledgeDocumentId are populated with the same kdId. But, I want to populate only KnowledgeDocumentId and stop KDReferenceId from populating and set it to null.

As both the fields are pointing to the same  reference, Entity framework is populating the Id on both the fields.

How can I achieve this still by saving the KnowledgeDocument with its children?

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your configuration. It's not clear why KDReferenceId would be set unless the mapping is treating it as a required FK.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the reason is in two identical relationships. You need to specify what properties are related. You can do it by [`InverseProperty`](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) attribute or by FluentAPI like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // configures one-to-many relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<KDValueCreation>()
        .HasRequired<KnowledgeDocument>(c => c.KnowledgeDocument)
        .WithMany(d => d.KDValueCreations)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.KnowledgeDocumentId);
      }
}
```

or this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<KnowledgeDocument>()
    .HasMany<KDValueCreation>(d => d.KDValueCreations)
    .WithRequired(c => c.KnowledgeDocument)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.KnowledgeDocumentId);
```